# Rest Kit load to CoreData by ID

Tags: core-data, mapping, restkit

Is there any way to make Restkit load relationship objects automatically by IDs and put them to CoreData?

Here's my JSONs

Waypoint:

```
{
  "date": "23 / 09 / 2012",
  "places_ids": [
    1182,
    1065,
    1140,
    1126
  ]
}
```

Place:

```
{
  "id": 1182,
  "name": "New-York",
  "temperature": 32
}
```

I want Reskit to load and map not only waypoint object, but all related Place objects.
Like so: "Restkit, please, load this Waypoint from url

```
.../api/waypoints/:id"
```

and it loads waypoint and all Place objects from url

```
.../api/places/:id
```

Now waypoint has 'places_ids' transformable attribute and 'places' relationship. And it's not convinient to load places match them with places.

Comment: The end of your question doesn't make sense. And no, RestKit won't automatically trigger follow-on downloads for you. It can populate relationships for you but you need to tell it what to download and when.

Answer (score 0):

Wain is right that Restkit won't automatically go out to the web and fetch a place for you.  At least as it was in RestKit 0.1 you're going to have to alter your json for waypoint from what you have to something like:

```
{"date": "23 / 09 / 2012",
  "places_ids": [
    {"id":1182},
    {"id":1065},
    {"id":1140},
    {"id":1126}
  ]
}
```

for it to understand that the place_ids represent another object in your graph.